# Python error message 'No error message is available' using win32api

Tags: python, winapi

There is a script that I made to move the cursor around the screen in Python 2.6. It moves with slight variation along a straight line. The speed is fixed and destination slightly variable as well.

```
import win32api, random, math

def cmouse(x2,y2):
    x1,y1 = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    x2 = x2 + random.randrange(-1, 2)
    y2 = y2 + random.randrange(-1, 2)
    dis_x = x2-x1
    dis_y = y2-y1
    dis = math.sqrt(math.pow(x2-x1, 2)+math.pow(y2-y1, 2))
    n = int((dis/2200)*100)
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        t = (random.randrange(1, 3)*0.005)
        c1,d1 = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        if c1 in range(x2-45, x2+46) and d1 in range(y2-45, y2+46):
            var_x = 0
            var_y = 0
        else:
            var_x = random.randrange(-3, 4)
            var_y = random.randrange(-3, 4)
        if n!=0:
            win32api.SetCursorPos((int(x1 + var_x + i*(float(dis_x)/n)),
                                   int(y1 + var_y + i*(float(dis_y)/n))))
            time.sleep(t)
        else:
            time.sleep(t)
            break
```

It works well 99.5% of the time, but sometimes I get this error.

```
File "C:\User\Desktop\Script.py", line 58, in cmouse
    win32api.SetCursorPos((int(x1 + var_x + i*(float(dis_x)/n)),
                           int(y1 + var_y + i*(float(dis_y)/n))))
error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

I can't find any way to fix this rare but annoying error. I'm quite sure it has to do with the win32api, but I am looking for some help.

Comment: Why not put a try/except block around the failing function and print the arguments when it fails?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python and do not know how to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're new to Python--as I suggested in a comment, you need to figure out which values cause the error when the function is called.  Try this:

```
try:
    win32api.SetCursorPos((int(x1 + var_x + i*(float(dis_x)/n)),
                           int(y1 + var_y + i*(float(dis_y)/n))))
except:
    print "error in SetCursorPos() with x1", x1, "y1", y1, "var_x", var_x, "var_y", var_y, "dis_x", dis_x, "dis_y", dis_y, "n", n
    raise
```

The idea is to briefly intercept the exception, print all the arguments which caused it, then let it propagate as it did before (possibly terminating the program).  Hopefully this will help you understand which arguments lead to errors.